# Cant closing Tag in foreach with Razor - ASP.NET MVC

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a `div` and each `div` has two `divs` in it like this:

```
<div class="col">
    <div class="item-c color1">..</div>
    <div class="item-c color2">..</div>
</div>
```

I read data from database and I want to repeat this div with a `foreach` statement.

I use below code but I get a `Runtime Error`

```
<div class="col">
@foreach (var item in Model)
{

    <div class="item-c  @("color" + index.ToString()) ">..</div>
    if (index % 2 == 0)
    {
        <text></div><div class="col"></text>
    }
    index++;
    if (index > 8) { index = 1; }
}
```

my result should like this :
[image]
I am getting this Error :

> Encountered end tag "div" with no matching start tag

Comment: Its unclear what your logic is. If your model contains 5 items are you expecting 3 `<div class="col">` with the first 2 containing 2 `<div class="item-c ...>` and the last one containing only `<div class="item-c color5>`?

Comment: `index % 2` is either `0` or `1`, but never `2`. Therefore, your `if`-block never executes.

Comment: @StephenMuecke yes , last one containing onle one `div`

Comment: @MariusSchulz yes , its wrong and updated

Comment: I don't get the logic...1. are you wanting to repeat col?, 2. why the logic in the repeat? if you are fetching form DB then i assume you know the amount of items, so just for-each over them, don't see why the index logic is needed.

Comment: updated post : add an example as my result

Comment: Could you include the mark for Model, reason i say is you could leverage off that... ie foreach col ... foreach item.  If you model does not support this can you change it to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code needs to be

```
@{ int index = 1; }

<div class="col">
    @foreach(var item in Model.Items)
    {
        <div class="item-c color@(index)">..</div>
        if (index % 2 == 0) // close the div and start a new one
        {
            @:</div><div class="col">
        }
        index++;
        if (index > 8) { index = 1; }
    }
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can always use `Html.Raw` in case if you need to close the tags inside the razor code. Checkout the below code which should work according to your requirement.

```
      <div class="col">
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {

                <div class="item-c  @("color" + index.ToString()) ">..</div>

                if (index % 2 == 2)
                {
                     @Html.Raw("</div> <div class="col">")

                }
                index++;
                if (index > 8) { index = 1; }

            }
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is incorrect, if the row count is odd, then you are not closing the last div, if your row count is even, your adding a open div and not closing it. 
Removing the `"if (index % 2 == 2)"` will produce the div as in your example

```
<div class="col">
  <div class="item-c color1">..</div>
  <div class="item-c color2">..</div>
</div>

<div class="col">
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
              <div class="item-c @("color" + index.ToString())">..</div>
              index++;
              if (index > 8) { index = 1; }
            }
</div>
```

Comment: I want put two divs in each Parent Div. div with class `col` that should include two divs no more . in your answer in each div more than div repeat.

Answer (score 0):

Why not something like

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div class="col">
        @foreach (var item2 in Model.Items.Select((model, index) => new { index, model }))
        {   
             <div class="item-c color@item2.index">

             </div>
        }
    </div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bit late to the party but I found this approach works for me and is also readable:

```
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.SlotValues.Length; i++)
        {
            string key = Model.SlotValues[i].Key;

            if (i % 2 == 0)
            {
                @:<div class="row">
            }

            <div class="col-md-6">
                <label for="@key" class="form-selector__form__label form-selector__form__label--small text--light">@key</label>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.SlotValues[i].Value, new { @class = "form-selector__form__input", placeholder = @key })
            </div>


            if (i % 2 == 1)
            {
                @:</div>
            }
        }
```